# Converting JS replace to Golang JS regexp

Tags: go

In Javascript I have a word replace function that I need to convert to GoLang, but it doesn't seems to be replacing. I believe there's something wrong with my regex in Golang.

**Working JS Example - Replacing street names acronyms with the full word.**
I cannot do plain replace because some of the words are at the end of the string, some of the words have white space before and after, and some are at the start of the string, hence my different regexp.

```
 word.replace(/ RD$/, ' ROAD')
    .replace(' RD ', ' ROAD ')
    .replace(' MKT ', ' MARKET ')
    .replace(' NTH ', ' NORTH ')
    .replace(/^NTH /, 'NORTH ')
    .replace(/ NTH$/, ' NORTH')
    .replace(' PK ', ' PARK ')
    .replace(/^STH /, 'SOUTH ')
    .replace(' STH ', ' SOUTH ')
    .replace(' ST ', ' STREET ')
```

**My attempt with GoLang.**

```
type Address struct {
   .....
   StreetName string
}

func (address *Address) replace(oldWord string, newWord string) {
    sampleRegexp := regexp.MustCompile(oldWord)

    result := sampleRegexp.ReplaceAllString(string(address.StreetName), newWord)

    fmt.Println(oldWord, newWord, result)
    address.StreetName = result

}
```

Then in my main.go I'm calling it like that

```
    address.replace(`/ RD$/`, " ROAD")
    address.replace(" RD ", " ROAD ")
    address.replace(" MKT ", " MARKET ")
    address.replace(" NTH ", " NORTH ")
    address.replace(`/^NTH /`, "NORTH ")
    address.replace(`/ NTH$/`, " NORTH")
    address.replace(" PK ", " PARK ")
    address.replace(`/^STH /`, "SOUTH ")
```

For example if the StreetName is `Market Rd`, i expect it to become `Market Road`, but it's not replacing.

Could it be because regexp is not of type `string` ?

I did up a simple [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Lzpr20BGTsO)

Comment: `/` makes no sense for go regex. It's just a literal slash. Also, you are probably missing the case insensitive flag `(?i)`. See https://pkg.go.dev/regexp/syntax@master

Comment: case sensitive! that was it, it's mistake of my part. Thank u!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the zero-length word boundary `\b`? That will anchor the match at any word boundary.

Then it's just a matter of:

https://go.dev/play/p/TKs1nIaRZWQ

```
func expandAbbreviations(s string) string {
  return rx.ReplaceAllStringFunc(s, func(m string) string {
    r := expansions[strings.ToLower(m)]
    if r == "" {
            r = m
        }
        return r
    })
}

var rx = regexp.MustCompile(`\b(?i:rd|mkt|nth|pk|sth|st)\b`)
var expansions = map[string]string{
    "rd":  "ROAD",
    "mkt": "MARKET",
    "nth": "NORTH",
    "pk":  "PARK",
    "sth": "SOUTH",
    "st":  "STREET",
}
```

which converts

```
Nth 123 Pk St Sth
```

to

```
NORTH 123 PARK STREET SOUTH
```